# Which groups have exactly the same rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

If I have a data frame like the following

| group1 | group2 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | ABC | 5 |
| A | 1 | DEF | 2 |
| B | 1 | AB | 1 |
| C | 1 | ABC | 5 |
| C | 1 | DEF | 2 |
| A | 2 | BC | 8 |
| B | 2 | AB | 1 |

We can see that the the (A, 1) and (C, 1) groups have the same rows (since col1 and col2 are the same within this group). The same is true for (B,1) and (B, 2).

So really we are left with 3 distinct "larger groups" (call them categories) in this data frame, namely:

| category | group1 | group2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | C | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 3 | A | 2 |

And I am wondering **how can I return the above data frame in R** given a data frame like the first? The order of the "category" column doesn't matter here, for example (A,2) could be group 1 instead of {(A,1), (C,1)}, as long as these have a distinct category index.

I have tried a few very long/inefficient ways of doing this in Dplyr but I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` first to handle identical groups over multiple rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = c(col1, col2)) %>% 
  group_by(across(-c(group1, group2))) %>% 
  mutate(category = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(category, group1, group2) %>% 
  arrange(category)
```

```
  category group1 group2
     <int> <chr>   <int>
1        1 B           1
2        1 B           2
3        2 A           1
4        2 C           1
5        3 A           2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first `group_by` "col1" and "col2" and select the duplicated rows.  Next, you can create a unique ID using `cur_group_id` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  filter(n() != 1) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-starts_with("col"))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   group1 group2    ID
#>   <chr>   <int> <int>
#> 1 A           1     2
#> 2 A           1     3
#> 3 B           1     1
#> 4 C           1     2
#> 5 C           1     3
#> 6 B           2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The expected output is somehow 5 rows?!

Comment: @TarJae, Yes that is strange because there is only one bc,8 while there is another group for A,1 C,1?

Comment: I have not find a solution allthough I tried a lot hmmmh

Comment: I think the thing is to consider also multiple rows belonging to the same group, i.e. the two rows of A1 and C1 which are identical should reduced to one row each.